# PHP unable to decode nested response from database

Tags: php

So I'am trying to decode the response iam getting. The current response iam now receiving is as follows;

```
[ { "RESPONSE": "{\"Result\":[{\"ERRORS\":\"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049\"}]}" }, { "RESPONSE": "{\"Result\":[{\"ERRORS\":\"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211048\"}]}" }, { "RESPONSE": "{\"Result\":[{\"ERRORS\":\"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211050\"}]}" }, { "RESPONSE": "{\"Result\":[{\"ERRORS\":\"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211050\"}]}" }, { "RESPONSE": "{\"Result\":[{\"ERRORS\":\"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049\"}]}" }, { "RESPONSE": "{\"Result\":[{\"ERRORS\":\"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211046\"}]}" },
```

This is how iam trying to get the decoded code:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //
//        $log = Log::get('RESPONSE');
        // Get all the Response rows from database.
        $data = Log::get('RESPONSE');

        // Convert data into json array
        //$decoded = json_encode($data, true);
//        dd($decoded);
        //$decoded = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        //$test_decoded = json_decode($decoded, true);
        //$test = json_decode($decoded, true);
//        foreach($decoded['RESPONSE'] as $response){
//            $response['Result'];
//            //json_decode($response);
//            //if ($response['Result'])
//        }
        //dd($decoded);
        //return($decoded);
        //$again_decode = json_decode($decoded);
        //$response_key_value = $decoded['RESPONSE'];

         //dd($test);

        $decoded = json_decode($data);

        return ($decoded);
    }
```

I have left all the commented code in so you will be able to see what i already have tried. What iam looking to achieve is the following:

```
 { "RESPONSE": 
     "{"Result":
        {"ERRORS":"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049"}
```

I think iam stuck with a nested json query and within that nested json query i have an array of one json query. is it possible to extract the last json query. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The value of your `RESPONSE` node is a **string** (hence the escaped `\"` in the value), so you need to `json_decode()` it too:

```
$decoded = \json_decode($data);
$responseDecoded = \json_decode($decoded['RESPONSE']);
\var_dump($responseDecoded);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I Still seem to get an Undefined index error. It is the following. Undefined index: RESPONSE. I thought ```$data = Log::get('RESPONSE'); ``` is the definition of the RESPONSE index. Or am i thinking wrong here